# HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am working on an application with Spring 4.1.6 and Hibernate 4.3. When deploying my application on the test server (Tomcat7) in Eclipse I get the following error:

```
015-10-29 18:15:28 WARN  JdbcServicesImpl:204 - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have tried out the following things :

1. Checked and rechecked my password.
2. Granted full access to `root@localhost` on the db

Here is the log:

```
2015-10-29 18:15:22 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:510 - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'recruitment-mvc-servlet': startup date [Thu Oct 29 18:15:22 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
  2015-10-29 18:15:23 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/recruitmentapp-context-config.xml]
  2015-10-29 18:15:24 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/recruitmentapp-multitenancy-config.xml]
  2015-10-29 18:15:24 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:822 - Overriding bean definition for bean 'loginController': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.ta.app.recruitment.web.controller.LoginController]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [F:\Work\dev\svn\Recruitment Workspaces\Release_1.1_29_10_2015\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Recruitment\WEB-INF\classes\com\ta\app\recruitment\web\controller\LoginController.class]] with [Generic bean: class [com.ta.app.recruitment.web.controller.LoginController]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/recruitmentapp-context-config.xml]]
  2015-10-29 18:15:24 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:822 - Overriding bean definition for bean 'candidateController': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.ta.app.recruitment.web.controller.CandidateController]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [F:\Work\dev\svn\Recruitment Workspaces\Release_1.1_29_10_2015\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Recruitment\WEB-INF\classes\com\ta\app\recruitment\web\controller\CandidateController.class]] with [Generic bean: class [com.ta.app.recruitment.web.controller.CandidateController]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/recruitmentapp-context-config.xml]]
  2015-10-29 18:15:24 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:822 - Overriding bean definition for bean 'interviewerController': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.ta.app.recruitment.web.controller.InterviewerController]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [F:\Work\dev\svn\Recruitment Workspaces\Release_1.1_29_10_2015\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Recruitment\WEB-INF\classes\com\ta\app\recruitment\web\controller\InterviewerController.class]] with [Generic bean: class [com.ta.app.recruitment.web.controller.InterviewerController]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/recruitmentapp-context-config.xml]]
  2015-10-29 18:15:24 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:822 - Overriding bean definition for bean 'recruiterController': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.ta.app.recruitment.web.controller.RecruiterController]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [F:\Work\dev\svn\Recruitment Workspaces\Release_1.1_29_10_2015\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Recruitment\WEB-INF\classes\com\ta\app\recruitment\web\controller\RecruiterController.class]] with [Generic bean: class [com.ta.app.recruitment.web.controller.RecruiterController]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/recruitmentapp-context-config.xml]]
  2015-10-29 18:15:24 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:822 - Overriding bean definition for bean 'searchController': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.ta.app.recruitment.web.controller.SearchController]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [F:\Work\dev\svn\Recruitment Workspaces\Release_1.1_29_10_2015\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Recruitment\WEB-INF\classes\com\ta\app\recruitment\web\controller\SearchController.class]] with [Generic bean: class [com.ta.app.recruitment.web.controller.SearchController]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/recruitmentapp-context-config.xml]]
  2015-10-29 18:15:24 INFO  DefaultListableBeanFactory:822 - Overriding bean definition for bean 'staticController': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.ta.app.recruitment.web.controller.StaticController]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [F:\Work\dev\svn\Recruitment Workspaces\Release_1.1_29_10_2015\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Recruitment\WEB-INF\classes\com\ta\app\recruitment\web\controller\StaticController.class]] with [Generic bean: class [com.ta.app.recruitment.web.controller.StaticController]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/recruitmentapp-context-config.xml]]
  2015-10-29 18:15:26 INFO  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer:172 - Loading properties file from class path resource [dbparams.properties]
  2015-10-29 18:15:26 INFO  DriverManagerDataSource:133 - Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  2015-10-29 18:15:27 INFO  Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
  2015-10-29 18:15:27 INFO  Version:54 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.2.Final}
  2015-10-29 18:15:27 INFO  Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
  2015-10-29 18:15:27 INFO  Environment:346 - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
  Datasource : org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@18229761
2015-10-29 18:15:28 WARN  JdbcServicesImpl:204 - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
  2015-10-29 18:15:28 INFO  Dialect:145 - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
  2015-10-29 18:15:28 INFO  LobCreatorBuilder:88 - HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
  2015-10-29 18:15:29 INFO  TransactionFactoryInitiator:62 - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
  2015-10-29 18:15:29 INFO  ASTQueryTranslatorFactory:47 - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
  2015-10-29 18:15:32 DEBUG MapperFactory:49 - Entering >> getMapperInstance()
  2015-10-29 18:15:32 DEBUG MapperFactory:50 - Parameters : jd.mapper
  2015-10-29 18:15:32 DEBUG EntityDTOMapper:62 - Entering >> constructor addressMapper
  2015-10-29 18:15:32 DEBUG MapperFactory:49 - Entering >> getMapperInstance()
  2015-10-29 18:15:32 DEBUG MapperFactory:50 - Parameters : skill.category.mapper
  2015-10-29 18:15:32 DEBUG MapperFactory:67
```

Here is my spring config file entry for the datasource:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="${hibernate.show_sql}" />
                <entry key="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8" />
                <entry key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8" />
                <entry key="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA" />
                <entry key="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider"
                    value-ref="tenantConnectionProvider" />
                <entry key="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value-ref="tenantIdentifierResolver"></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
```

Here are my project dependencies:

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.2.Final</hibernate.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <json.version>2.4</json.version>
        <servlet.version>3.0.1</servlet.version>
        <jsp.version>2.2.1</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <shiro.version>1.2.3</shiro.version>
        <context.path>Recruitment</context.path>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
            <version>${shiro.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
          <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
          <version>${shiro.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
          <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
          <version>${shiro.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ta.app.recruitment</groupId>
            <artifactId>recruitment.core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>${json.version}</version>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.cssbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdf2dom</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.01</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Another project in the same workspace connecting to the same database works just fine. Its main difference is that it does not have the Apache POI dependencies.

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure out the issue here. Apparently I was using an older version of the database schema that did not have a couple of tables that the code (which was a later version) expected.